# C# switch case with constant values as case condition

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am using C# (8.0) switch statement as shown here:

```
var operation = 2;  

var result = operation switch  
{  
    1 => "Case 1",  
    2 => "Case 2",  
    3 => "Case 3",  
    4 => "Case 4",  
    _ => "No case available"  
};
```

I would like to check if we can apply some constant variable which will has some values in it to match with case condition - for example:

```
public static readonly string operation1 = "1";
public static readonly string operation2 = "2";

var result = operation switch  
{  
    operation1  => "Case 1",  
    operation2  => "Case 2",  
    _ => "No case available"  
};
```

Kindly let me know if there is any better way to handle this I don't want to hard code the values in the switch statement as per standards and we maintain the constants in one place and referring to them in the projects at different sections

Comment: This is quickly becoming very ugly, and probably not very easily maintainable.  I think your team ought to rethink the whole thing.  I'd start by evaluating whether or not you really need a factory method (which is what this seems like it is).  Then, I'd ask, "Do we really need generic operations, and should they be called "operation1" or something more descriptive?  If these are actual operations, you're probably better served by simply making them methods with descriptive names.  Finally, you should read https://xyproblem.info.

Comment: Would an enum make this more clear than a bunch of string constants?

Answer (score 2):

[Constant expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const) can be used in `switch` statement/expression directly via [constant pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#constant-pattern):

```
const string operation1 = "1";
const string operation2 = "2";

var result = operation switch  
{  
    operation1  => "Case 1",  
    operation2  => "Case 2",  
    _ => "No case available"  
};
```

But if it is a variable and not a constant then [var pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern) with [case guards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression#case-guards) can be used instead:

```
var operation1 = "1";
var operation2 = "2";

var result = operation switch  
{  
    var c1 when c1 == operation1  => "Case 1",  
    var c2 when c2 == operation2  => "Case 2",  
    _ => "No case available"  
};
```